# Cypher create query with parameter which is not in entity

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, repository

I have an entity with all required annotations, getters.

```
public class SomeEntity {
    private String id; 
    private String name; 
}
```

And I have a repository

```
public interface SomeRepository extends Neo4jRepository<SomeEntity, String> {

     @Query(value="some query")
     void someMethod(String id, String name, String parameter)
}
```

Can I somehow pass `parameter` variable to query without defining it in the entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder {0}..{n} to match the method's parameters

```
@Query(value="MATCH (a:A) where a.id = {0} AND a.name = {1} and a.param = {2}")
void someMethod(String id, String name, String parameter)
```